# How to create an image that get bigger as you click it

Tags: html, image, gallery

I've got an image gallery and I want to make it so that when you click on an individual picture it gets bigger, fullscreen etc.

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img.jpg">
   <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img3.jpeg">
    <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img4.jpg">
  <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img5.jpg">
  <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img7.jpg">
  <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img8.jpg">
  <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img9.jpg">
     <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img10.jpg">
     <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img11.jpg">
     <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img2.jpg">
     <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img6.jpg">
     <img class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="smilecup.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add IDs to each div and edit them in JS:

```js
function increase(id) {
    element = document.getElementById(id);
    width = element.clientWidth;
    element.style.width = String(width+10)+"px"
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <img id = "1" onclick="increase('1')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img.jpg">
   <img id = "2" onclick="increase('2')"class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img3.jpeg">
    <img id = "3" onclick="increase('3')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img4.jpg">
  <img id = "4" onclick="increase('4')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img5.jpg">
  <img id = "5" onclick="increase('5')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img7.jpg">
  <img id = "6" onclick="increase('6')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img8.jpg">
  <img id = "7" onclick="increase('7')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img9.jpg">
     <img id = "8" onclick="increase('8')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img10.jpg">
     <img id = "9" onclick="increase('9')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img11.jpg">
     <img id = "10" onclick="increase('10')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img2.jpg">
     <img id = "11" onclick="increase('11')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img6.jpg">
     <img id = "12" onclick="increase('12')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="smilecup.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

And for full screen:

```js
function increase(id) {
    element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.width = window.innerWidth+"px"
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <img id = "1" onclick="increase('1')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img.jpg">
   <img id = "2" onclick="increase('2')"class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img3.jpeg">
    <img id = "3" onclick="increase('3')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img4.jpg">
  <img id = "4" onclick="increase('4')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop1" src="img5.jpg">
  <img id = "5" onclick="increase('5')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img7.jpg">
  <img id = "6" onclick="increase('6')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img8.jpg">
  <img id = "7" onclick="increase('7')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img9.jpg">
     <img id = "8" onclick="increase('8')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img10.jpg">
     <img id = "9" onclick="increase('9')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img11.jpg">
     <img id = "10" onclick="increase('10')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img2.jpg">
     <img id = "11" onclick="increase('11')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="img6.jpg">
     <img id = "12" onclick="increase('12')" class="col-xs-3 paddingtop" src="smilecup.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this out and let you know how it went. I've had some issues with Javascript not working though. I make a new file, save it as a .Js and put a link in my website folder but it doesn't show up. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using? You may have accidentally disabled JS. Also, how are you accessing the HTML?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and I access the HTML through Sublime Text Editor, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Do other websites function well?

Comment: Yeah, never really had a problem like that

Comment: Try a different browser.

Comment: Sorry for such a late response but I tried it out and it didn't work. I created a .js file for the function increase(id) {
    element = document.getElementById(id);
    width = element.clientWidth;
    element.style.width = String(width+10)+"px"
}                                                                                                                                             and changed my images

Comment: Try using `<script></script>` inline JS. Then we can know if it's a problem with my code or your implementation.

Comment: It kind of worked, it permanently made the second image massive but did nothing to the others.

Comment: @sruli Here's a few things you can try: A different browser, changing the image, inline javascript. If I think of anything else, I'll let you know.